# UIWebView not scrolling issue in IOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am facing a strange problem. I have created a local .html file using the 
following code. The code is working till iOS9 but in iOS10 UIWebView is not scrolling.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.myWebView.delegate = self;
self.myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
NSString *htmlBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
htmlBody = [htmlBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Most-Common-Que3-Paragraph1" withString:@"In a small village, a little boy lived with his father and mother. He was the only son.The parents of the little boy were very depressed due to his bad temper"];
[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.myWebView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
```

Comment: Added still facing the same issue

Comment: Tryself.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;

Comment: Also are you using clipstobounds?